# Rank of the matrix $P=X(X^TX)^{-1}X'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

$X$ is an $n×p$ matrix, with $Rank(X)=r$. Then what is the Rank of the matrix $P=X(X^TX)^{-1}X'$? Is it always true that $Rank(X)= Rank(P)$? Is it true when $X$ is of full column rank, i.e. $p=r$?

I know that $Rank(X)=Rank(X'X)$, but I am confused with the above questions. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X^\top X$ is invertible only when $r=p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ted's comment says, $X^\top X$ is invertible only when $r = p$, so we can assume that $X$ has rank $p$ (otherwise $P$ does not exist). There is already a simple proof in this [StackExchange answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1582683/1047463) that the rank of $P$ is $p$, using the fact that $P$ is idempotent and that the trace of an idempotent matrix is equal to the rank of the matrix. If you want a proof of the fact that the trace of an idempotent matrix is equal to the rank of the matrix, please see this [StackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101512/proving-the-trace-of-an-idempotent-matrix-equals-the-rank-of-the-matrix).