# Proof that $\textbf{Q} = \textbf{I}_n - \textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^T$ is of rank $n-k-1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $n > k$. Let $\textbf{Q} = \textbf{I}_n - \textbf{X}(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}^T$ where $\textbf{I}_n$ is an $n \times n$ identity matrix, $\textbf{X}$ is a $n \times (k+1)$ matrix with rank $k+1$ and the first column of $\textbf{X}$ contains only of $1$'s. I would like to show that $\textbf{Q}$ has rank $n-k-1$.

First note that $\textbf{Q}\textbf{X} = \boldsymbol{0}$ and $\textbf{Q}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Because $\textbf{Q}\textbf{X} = \boldsymbol{0}$, the rows of $\textbf{Q}$ satisfy the following $k + 1$ constraints:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^nq_{ji} &= 0, \ j = 1, \dotsc, n;\\
\sum_{j=1}^nq_{ji}x_{i1} &= 0, \ j = 1, \dotsc, n;\\
&\vdots\\
\sum_{j=1}^nq_{ji}x_{ik} &= 0, \ j = 1, \dotsc, n.
\end{align*}

I feel like I am almost there, but I can't seem to explain why the rank of $\textbf{Q}$ is $n-k-1$ using these constrains.

Comment: $Q$ is idempotent since the hat matrix $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is idempotent. And rank of idempotent matrix equals its trace. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1582567/321264

Comment: But I dont know the elements of $Q$ on the diagonal, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $\ X\ $ has $\ k+1\ $ linearly independent columns.  Let $\ S\ $ be the set of row vectors orthogonal to the column space of $\ X\ $.  Then $\ S\ $ has dimension $\ n-k-1\ $, and for any $\ v\in S\ $,
\begin{align}
vQ&=v-vX\big(X^TX\big)^{-1}X^T\\
&=v\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ v\ $ is in the row space of $\ Q_\ $.  Therefore, the dimension of the row space, and hence the rank of $\ Q\ $ is at least $\ n-k-1\ $.

But $\ QX=0\ $, so the kernel of $\ Q\ $ contains the column space of $\ X\ $ and therefore has dimension at least $\ k+1\ $. By the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), therefore,
$$
k+1\le\dim\ker Q=n-\text{rank}\,Q\ ,
$$
giving $\ \text{rank}\,Q\le n-k-1\ $, and hence $\ \text{rank}\,Q= n-k-1\ $.

Comment: Why would $v$ be in the row space of $Q$? Shouldn't $v$ be transposed?

Comment: $\ v $  is in $\ S\ $, the orthogonal complement of the *column space* of $\ X\ $.  I'm assuming that vectors in the orthogonal complement of a space of column vectors to be already row vectors without transposition. I've now reworded the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Which answer are you referring to? The one from River Li? There, I don't understand the inequality $r(Q) \geq n - (k+1)$. Is $r(Q + Y) = n$? Also, why $vX(X^TX)^{-1}X^T = 0$? Is it simply because $v$ is orthogonal to the columns of $X$?

Comment: I'm simply answering your question about $\ v\ $ (which doesn't appear in River Li's answer).  In River Li's answer $\ r(Q+Y)=n\ $ because $\ Q+Y=I_n\ $.  And yes, if $\ v\ $ is orthogonal to allthe columns of $\ X\ $, then $\ vX=0\ $.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the rank of $A$ by $r(A)$.

Denote $Y = X(X^\mathsf{T} X)^{-1}X^{\mathsf{T}}$. We have $r(Y) = k + 1$.

Using $r(A + B) \le r(A) + r(B)$, we have
$$r(Q + Y) 
\le r(Q) + r(Y)$$
which results in
$$r(Q) \ge n - (k + 1).$$

Using $r(AB) \ge r(A) + r(B) - n$, we have
$$r(QX) \ge r(Q) + r(X) - n$$
which results in (using $QX = 0$)
$$r(Q) \le n - (k + 1).$$

Thus, $r(Q) = n - (k + 1)$.

Comment: Why $r(Q) \geq n - (k+1)$? Is $r(Q + Y) = n?$

Comment: @VicRyan I did not get the notification. Perhaps you may use @. Yes. $Q + Y = I_n$ and $\mathrm{rank}(I_n) = n$.